# Не могу отключить прокрутку в модальном окне

Tags: javascript, css

Не получается убрать скролл бар при открытом модальном окне, пыталась через `overflow-y:hidden` с добавлением функции, но ничего не получилось. Что мне стоит сделать, чтобы убрать скролл бар в модальном окне, ну и собственно чтобы появлялся при закрытии оного?

Код и всё-всё находится тут. https://dropmefiles.com/48oP6  Пароль:NioD8D

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(popup, 3000);
    function popup() {
        $("#logindiv").css("display", "block");
    }

    $("#login #cancel").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();
    });
    $("#onclick, #onclick1, #onclick2").click(function () {
        $("#contactdiv").css("display", "block");
    });
    $("#contact #cancel").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().hide();
    });
});
```

**Стили:**

```
#contactdiv{
    z-index: 10;
    opacity:0.92;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    display: none;
}
#logindiv{
    opacity:0.92;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: вы бы рабочий код показали , и можно было бы говорить о том где прокрутка

Comment: единственное что могу сказать по вашему коды, это то, что вместо `.css("display", "block")`, можно использовать `.show()`, и дальше не тёмный лес, не понятно даже у какого элемента нужно убрать скролл бар

Answer (score 1):

Собственно разобралась сама, исправила код на (представила ниже, и все сработало). :)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(popup, 3000);
function popup() {
$("#logindiv").css("display", "block");
$('body').css('overflow','hidden')  
}
$("#login #cancel").click(function() {
$('body').css('overflow-y','scroll')
$(this).parent().parent().hide();
});

$("#onclick, #onclick1, #onclick2").click(function() {
$('body').css('overflow','hidden')
$("#contactdiv").css("display", "block");
});
$("#contact #cancel").click(function() {
$('body').css('overflow-y','scroll')
$(this).parent().parent().hide();
});
```